# Uialertview and memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uialertview

If I `alloc unit` a UIAlertview and then `show` it. Should I `release` it after the `show` or should I `autorelease` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the common way of showing an alert:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Title:" 
                                                message: @"The Message"
                                               delegate: self
                                      cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: Only [alert show] is the common way of showing an alert, the rest has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I don't think `[alert show]` will do very much without the line above it.

Answer (score 2):

Release it after the show. It will retain itself until no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is good programming style to release it manually. Autorelease will also do the same thing but at it's own time. So it might release it latter also.