# iPhone UIAlertview abandon memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, uialertview, memory-leaks

I use UIAlertview to input some text, and it works fine. 
However, after the alertview is closed, there is still more than 17MB increase in memory before alertview is opened(from 9MB to 26 MB). I used Instrument Allocation to measure heap memory and activity monitor to measure it. Both of them show the similar result. When I switch to other App, the memory increased by alertview will be reduced to the proper level. Is it normal ? My environment is iPhone4+iOS6.
Here's some code for trying.

```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"input caption" message:@"text"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
   [alert show];
   [alert release];
```

Thank you.

---

Dear Naveed S and Purr,
   Thank you very much.
I'm not sure I follow your suggestion correctly. But I use Activity monitor watch the Real mem, the memory still increase about 20 MB after alertview is closed. I remove [alert release] after [alert show], and I wrote

```
  [alert show];
 //[alert release];

 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 { [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
  [alertView autorelease];                                                      }
```

Moreovre, the memory is reduced when the app enter background mode after I press home. (This is similar as my previous code).  How could I watch the abandon memory correctly. I'm even not sure how to watch it in the right way.....

BTW, my original codes follow the post here.  [Uialertview and memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365064/uialertview-and-memory-management)

Comment: I don't think you should see a 20MB surge in memory due to UIAlertView. There must be something else happening....

Comment: I use instrument Activity monitor to look at the real mem, it show 9.20 MB before show alertview, but it show 26 MB after closing alertview. I continue doing it again and again, the real mem shows near 26 MB steadily. And when I open safari or press home, it shows 11.6MB. I guess iOS do some memory cache for alertview or textfield(there's a textfield in alertview). And this cache will be reduced when switching to other app. To sum up, I think it's abnormal, but I don't how to solve it.

Comment: What code is called when the alert closes?

Comment: I don't know what code is needed to call when alert close, here's my case           - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [textfieldCaption resignFirstResponder];
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        
    }
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
    // CRASH  [alertView release];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you should autorelease your alertView. `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` is called by the `UIAlertView`, so the alertView object should still be valid (not `-release'd`) when your method returns.

Better yet, convert to ARC and be done with manual `-retain`, `-release` and `-autorelease` ;)

If you're not converting to ARC, do this: remove the -release from the code in your original post, uncomment the `//CRASH` in your `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method and change the `-release` to `-autorelease` there.

Comment: Dear Naveed S and Purr, Thank you very much. I'm not sure I follow your suggestion correctly. But I use Activity monitor watch the Real mem, the memory still increase about 20 MB after alertview is closed. I remove [alert release] after [alert show], and I wrote
  [alert show];
 //[alert release];

 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 { [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
  [alertView autorelease];